# Issue accessing class variable from thread

Tags: java, multithreading

The code below is meant to take an arraylist of product objects as an input, spun thread for each product(and add the product to the arraylist 'products'), check product image(product.imageURL) availability, remove the products without images(remove the product from the arraylist 'products'), and return an arraylist of products with image available.

```
package com.catgen.thread;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.catgen.Product;
import com.catgen.Utils;

public class ProductFilterThread extends Thread{

    private Product product;
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public ProductFilterThread(){
    }

    public ProductFilterThread(Product product){
        this.product = product;
    }

    public synchronized void addProduct(Product product){
         System.out.println("Before add: "+getProducts().size());
         getProducts().add(product);
         System.out.println("After add: "+getProducts().size());
    }

    public synchronized void removeProduct(Product product){
         System.out.println("Before rem: "+getProducts().size());
         getProducts().remove(product);
         System.out.println("After rem: "+getProducts().size());
    }

    public synchronized List<Product> getProducts(){
        return this.products;
    }

    public synchronized void setProducts(List<Product> products){
        this.products = products;
    }

    public void run(){
        boolean imageExists = Utils.fileExists(this.product.ImageURL);
        if(!imageExists){
            System.out.println(this.product.ImageURL);
            removeProduct(this.product);
        }
    }

    public List<Product> getProductsWithImageOnly(List<Product> products){
        ProductFilterThread pft = null;
        try{
            List<ProductFilterThread> threads = new ArrayList<ProductFilterThread>();
            for(Product product: products){
                pft = new ProductFilterThread(product);
                addProduct(product);
                pft.start();
                threads.add(pft);
            }
            Iterator<ProductFilterThread> threadsIter = threads.iterator();
            while(threadsIter.hasNext()){
                ProductFilterThread thread = threadsIter.next();
                thread.join();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Total returned products = "+getProducts().size());
        return getProducts();
    }
}
```

Calling statement:

```
displayProducts = new ProductFilterThread().getProductsWithImageOnly(displayProducts);
```

Here, when addProduct(product) is called from within getProductsWithImageOnly(), getProducts() returns the list of products, but that's not the case(no products are returned) when the method removeProduct() is called by a thread, because of which the products without images are never removed. As a result, all the products are returned by the module whether or not the contained products have images.

What can be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.
James.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `ProductFilterThread` each iteration in the loop:

```
new ProductFilterThread(product);
```

Each `ProductFilterThread` has its own

```
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

So when you, in the `run` method, do

```
removeProduct(this.product);
```

you're removing the product from it's own `products` instance.

I suggest you design it differently, by perhaps giving the products-list the thread should work with, as argument to the `ProductFilterThread`:

```
private List<Product> products;

public ProductFilterThread(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}
```

But I must say that you should think carefully when working with multiple threads like this. You need to synchronize the access to the data structures carefully.

Comment: Thanks, that did the magic! But I noticed that the time taken has manifolded significantly. Could that be because of the additional parameter?

Comment: No, that's most likely due to the overhead and synchronization on the data structures. You would be better of using a thread pool for this, in which you run roughly as many threads as you have cores on your machine.

Comment: ... and, is it heap efficient?

Comment: Don't know really. Depends on what your bottle neck is. Have you profiled it?

Comment: Getting down to the basics,
How can we make a class variable accessible to all the threads spun from within the class? 

I think we can have two constructors here, one with argument 'products', and another, 'product'. While instantiating the class for the first time, we can pass the 'products' argument and set is as a variable, and accessible to all the other threads spun with 'product' argument, thereby allowing all the other threads to access the 'products' variable.

Comment: Sure. That sounds like a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you `products` list to be shared by all Filter Threads then you'll have to make it static. Fields are [confined to a single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644771/using-volatile-keyword/2644812#2644812).

Another remark - maybe you should rewrite your getter/setter methods for `products` to export an unmodifiable list and to read the input in a newly created list. Otherwise this can be the cause for multiple headaches in this multithreaded design (just imagine another thread 'getting' the list and modifying it while the filtering is active..)

Comment: Making the arraylist static would share it with threads spun by another request as you said. There should be one copy of the arraylist for (all the threads of) each request. But i'm totally lost in variable scope here when it comes to threads.

About your point on exporting an unmodifiable list, that would require a callback(kind of action) to read it from within getProductsWithImageOnly() right? I'll check that out.