# Volatile variable explanation in Java docs

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

> when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change

This is mentioned at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Can someone please provide an example of this?

This first gave me an impression that the thread that reads a volatile variable will synchronize with the writer thread and wait until the write is done. But that clearly is not the case.

An example would help a lot and be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mustafa

Comment: Volatile fields *do* establish a [synchronization order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4): "A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order)." However, this *does not* mean that an arbitrary write will occur before an arbitrary read (the order is established as the *result* of a write).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say you have the following class:

```
public class Shared {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public volatile int c;
}
```

Now let's say that thread A has a reference to an instance of this class and does

```
shared.a = 1;
shared.b = 2;
shared.c = 3;
```

And let's say that thread B has a reference to the same instance and does

```
display(c);
display(b);
display(a);
```

Then, if the value displayed for c is 3 (i.e. if the write of thread A has happened before the read of thread B), then it's guaranteed by the Java memory model that 2 and 1 will also be displayed for b and a respectively, because all the actions of thread A that have been made prior to the write to the volatile c are guaranteed to be visible by a thread that has read the new value of c.

Comment: Thanks. The statement makes much more sense now. For now my purpose is served. Mush appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the text of the document, if the *volatile* modifier is applied to the field, then it guarantees the following: if the *volatile*-field is changed in the code, then this change will occur **after** all operations preceding it, and **before** all operations, following it, and this will be the case for all application threads.