# Thread stuck busy waiting under some circumstances and not under others

Tags: java, multithreading, busy-waiting

I'm having a pretty weird problem with a java thread busy-waiting.

I have one thread that busy waits on the state of a static variable of some other thread. Let's say the thread that busy waits is waiting for another thread's static int variable to reach a certain value

```
while(OtherThread.countInt < 5);
```

If I use the above code, the thread will be stuck busy-waiting and will not break out of the while loop, even if `static int countInt` does reach 5.

```
while(OtherThread.countInt < 5) {
    // waste some time doing meaningless work
}
```

If I use this other code, however, then the thread **does** break out of the busy-wait loop. Sometimes, as soon as `countInt` reaches 5, other times a little while after. But it happens. For my particular example, I used this as the "meaningless work"

`print("busy waiting...",1000)    // wasting time doing meaningless work`

where I defined `print` as `synchronzied static void print(String s, int n)` that prints string `s` and then sleeps for `n` milliseconds.

What gives? Why does the thread get stuck busy waiting on the first code, but not on the other? All threads have same priorities, so it can't be a priority issue.

Comment: Is that `countInt` a `volatile` field?

Comment: "// waste some time doing meaningless work" Why not just wait for something like a `CountdownLatch` or a `Semaphore`?

Comment: I wanted a very simple example. I didn't think it could get any simpler than just printing to the console and then sleeping for a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

`countInt` isn't `volatile`, therefore the change isn't guaranteed to be visible to the waiting thread.

Since your `print()` method is `synchronized` it's likely creating a sufficient memory barrier that the updated value becomes visible to your `while` loop. This is essentially a coincidence; the `while` conditional itself is still broken. That's why it's so important to properly design and test concurrent code - it's easy to write something that only *appears* to work as intended, but will fail later (e.g. under load, on a different processor, after a seemingly-safe refactoring, etc.).

Use a proper memory barrier, such as a `synchronised` read and write, a `volatile` field, or a cross-thread communcation mechanism such as those in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). There are a number of [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3488703/113632) exploring `volatile` and these other tools.

You'd also do well to study [Java's concurrency support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). Cross-thread communication is non-trivial.

Comment: @Thilo in the question it's specified as a "*`static int countInt`*".

Comment: how does that explain the second busy-wait loop (the one that has the thread doing work in the body) breaking out?

edit: forgot to mention, thank you for the resources. I'll be sure to look into them.

Comment: @Manuel added some more detail to my answer.