# java synchronized keyword needed on primitive getter / setter method?

Tags: java, synchronized

I read some java code, and found these functions:

```
synchronized void setConnected(boolean connected){
   this.connected = connected;
}

synchronized boolean isConnected(){
   return connected;
}
```

I wonder if synchronization makes any sense here, or just author didn't understand the need for synchronized keyword?

I'd suppose that synchronized is useless here. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: The synchronized modifier only makes sense if more than one thread is going to attempt to access the `connected` variable - at least that's my understanding.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459543/java-synchronized-getters-and-setters. It answers your question and places it nicely in a larger context.

Comment: read these Q + A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459543/java-synchronized-getters-and-setters

Comment: `synchronized` method makes sense here (Of course when this code is executed in multi-threaded environment). It will allow the `connected` variable to be accessed in a thread safe way. Why do you think it's useless?

Comment: @StevenWolfe, this is not correct, things are not that simple (or, in other words, are way more complicated...). Without `synchronized`, it is possible that reader threads doesn't see the modification made by even one single writer thread.

Comment: @Bruno Reis, I'm not so sure about that otherwise I'd be forever adding `synchronized` to all my getter and setter methods - or I'd be then forced to make all my member variables `volatile`. If multiple threads aren't being utilized then the `synchronized` modifier is unnecessary.

Comment: @StevenWolfe, true, synchronized is useless if you have only one thread. I assume we are discussing multithreaded applications. However, it is true that this is unclear in the question.

Comment: Please refer an explanation here [1]-


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23213409/3559363

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The keyword `synchronized` is one way of ensuring thread-safety. Beware: there's (way) more to thread-safety than deadlocks, or missing updates because of two threads incrementing an int without synchronization.

Consider the following class:

```
class Connection {
  private boolean connected; 
  synchronized void setConnected(boolean connected){
    this.connected = connected;
  }
  synchronized boolean isConnected(){
    return connected;
  }
}
```

If multiple threads share an instance of `Connection` and one thread calls `setConnected(true)`, without `synchronized` it is possible that other threads keep seeing `isConnected() == false`. The `synchronized` keyword guarantees that all threads sees the current value of the field.

In more technical terms, the `synchronized` keyword ensures a **memory barrier** (hint: google that).

In more details: every write made before releasing a monitor (ie, before leaving a `synchronized` block) is guaranteed to be seen by every read made after acquiring the same monitor (ie, after entering a block synchronizing on the same object). In Java, there's something called *happens-before* (hint: google that), which is not as trivial as "I wrote the code in this order, so things get executed in this order". Using `synchronized` is a way to establish a happens-before relationship and guarantee that threads see the memory as you would expect them to see.

Another way to achieve the same guarantees, in this case, would be to eliminate the `synchronized` keyword and mark the field `volatile`. The guarantees provided by `volatile` are as follows: all writes made by a thread before a volatile write are guaranteed to be visible to a thread after a subsequent volatile read of the same field.

As a final note, in this particular case it might be better to use a `volatile` field instead of `synchronized` accessors, because the two approaches provide the same guarantees and the `volatile`-field approach allows simultaneous accesses to the field from different threads (which might improve performance if the `synchronized` version has too much contention).

Comment: However, some consider a slightly better practice to sync on a final field, as suggested by Mr. Skeet at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field

Comment: My question is maybe stupid, but your boolean should not be `volatile` ?

Comment: @pith: no, since all the accesses to it (ie, all reads and writes) are done inside synchronized methods.

Answer (score 8):

Synchronization is needed here to prevent memory consistency errors, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html. Though in this concrete case `volatile` would be much more efficient solution

```
private volatile boolean connected;

void setConnected(boolean connected){
   this.connected = connected;
}

boolean isConnected(){
   return connected;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

The author has probably designed the code with a multi-threaded approach in mind. This means that the methods are synchronized and more than one thread will not be able to access the synchronized code at the same time on the same object instance.