# Proper use of volatile variables and synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I am trying to wrap my head around thread safety in java (or in general). I have this class (which I hope complies with the definition of a POJO) which also needs to be compatible with JPA providers:

```
    public class SomeClass {

        private Object timestampLock = new Object();
        // are "volatile"s necessary?
        private volatile java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;
        private volatile String timestampTimeZoneName;

        private volatile BigDecimal someValue;

        public ZonedDateTime getTimestamp() {
            // is synchronisation necessary here? is this the correct usage?
            synchronized (timestampLock) {
                return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(timestampTimeZoneName));
            }
        }

        public void setTimestamp(ZonedDateTime dateTime) {
            // is this the correct usage?
            synchronized (timestampLock) {
                this.timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.from(dateTime.toInstant());
                this.timestampTimeZoneName = dateTime.getZone().getId();
            }
        }

        // is synchronisation required?
        public BigDecimal getSomeValue() {
            return someValue;
        }

        // is synchronisation required?
        public void setSomeValue(BigDecimal val) {
            someValue = val;
        }
    }
```

As stated in the commented rows in the code, is it necessary to define `timestamp` and `timestampTimeZoneName` as `volatile` and are the `synchronized` blocks used as they should be? Or should I use only the `synchronized` blocks and not define `timestamp` and `timestampTimeZoneName` as `volatile`? A `timestampTimeZoneName` of a `timestamp` should not be erroneously matched with another `timestamp`'s.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) link says

> Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile
>   (including long and double variables)

Should I understand that accesses to `someValue` in this code through the setter/getter are thread safe thanks to `volatile` definitions? If so, is there a better (I do not know what "better" might mean here) way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you going to use `SomeClass` as a JPA entity?

Comment: yes, I will use it as a JPA entity

Comment: `EntityManager` and `@Entity` classes should not be exposed to concurrent access from multiple threads. 
Check [Transactions and Concurrency chapter from Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/transactions.html).  
All in all I suggest applying synchronization to your business logic.

Comment: I want to experiment on asynchronous updating of entities from the database. Like a worker thread periodically refreshing select entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if you need synchronized, try to imagine a place where you can have a context switch that would break your code.

In this case, if the context switch happens where I put the comment, then in `getTimestamp()` you're going to be reading different values from each timestamp type.

Also, although assignments are atomic, this expression `java.sql.Timestamp.from(dateTime.toInstant());` certainly isn't, so you can get a context switch inbetween `dateTime.toInstant()` and the call to `from`. In short you definitely need the synchronized blocks.

```
synchronized (timestampLock) {
    this.timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.from(dateTime.toInstant());
    //CONTEXT SWITCH HERE
    this.timestampTimeZoneName = dateTime.getZone().getId();
}

synchronized (timestampLock) {
    return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(timestampTimeZoneName));
}
```

In terms of volatile, I'm pretty sure they're required. You have to guarantee that each thread definitely is getting the most updated version of a variable.

This is the contract of volatile. And although it may be covered by the synchronized block, and volatile not actually necessary here, it's good to write anyway. If the synchronized block does the job of volatile already, the VM won't do the guarantee twice. This means volatile won't cost you any more, and it's a very good flashing light that says to the programmer: "I'M USED IN MULTIPLE THREADS".

---

For `someValue`: If there's no synchronized block here, then volatile is definitely necessary. If you call a set in one thread, the other thread has no queue that tells it that may have been updated outside of this thread. So it may use an old and cached value. The JIT can do a lot of funny optimizations if it assumes single thread. Ones that can simply break your program.

Now I'm not entirely certain if synchronized is **required** here. My guess is no. I would add it anyway to be safe though. Or you can let java worry about the synchronization and use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: what about "volatile"s? do I need them for timestamp and/or timestampTimeZoneName? and for getting and setting someValue?

Comment: @mevtagezer see last paragraph

Comment: since getter gives out a new ZonedDateTime and setter replaces the private fields. it "feels" like the volatile definitions for timestamp and timestampTimeZoneName are not necessary. would it be if these fields were to be used another place in the class (other than getter/setter)?

Comment: @mevtagezer It's certainly possible that it may not matter in this case. I'm not 100% on the details. However, if it doesn't matter, then that means the synchronized block does the job of the volatile variable, and thus the volatile variables incurs no more overhead. Meaning you get it for free. However having volatile in the definition is helpful to the programmer. It tells them: "Hey, this may be accessed across multiple threads!". Which is a nice thing to know.

Comment: any idea on volatility and sychronisation requirement of "someValue"?

Comment: @mevtagezer volatile is definitely necessary there(if there's no synchronized). And I don't think you need synchronization. If the operation incremented, or in some way used the old value in the calculation of the expression then it would be necessary to synchronize. But I would probably synchronize it anyway. For that you may want to use this though: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: could you add your last comments to your answer?

Comment: @mevtagezer included. Let me know if this is now sufficient information for your question.

Comment: As long as there is no relationship between `someValue` and another property that needs an update, declaring it `volatile` is enough. (Note that the fact that `BigDecimal` is immutable is important as well here). So you can remove the “I'm not entirely certain” phrase. For the other variables, guarded by `synchronized(timestampLock)`, no `volatile` is required and I recommend removing them to make clear *which* thread-safety construct is the effective one here. But it’s strongly recommended to declare `timestampLock` as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing new here, this is just a more explicit version of something @Cruncher already said:

You need `synchronized` whenever it is important for two or more fields in your program to be consistent with one another.  Suppose you have two parallel lists, and your code depends on them both being the same length.  That's called an *invariant* as in, the two lists are *invariably* the same length.

How can you write a method, append(x,y), that adds a new pair of values to the lists without temporarily breaking the invariant?  You can't.  The method *must* add one item to the first list, breaking the invariant, and then add the other item to the second list, fixing it again.  There's no other way.

In a single-threaded program, that temporary broken state is no problem because no other method can possibly use the lists while append(x,y) is running.  That's no longer true in a multithreaded program.  In the worst case, append(x,y) could add x to the x list, and then the scheduler could suspend the thread at that exact moment to allow other threads to run.  The CPUs could execute millions of instructions before append(x,y) gets to finish the job and make the lists right again.  During all of that time, other threads would see the broken invariant, and possibly corrupt your data or crash the program as a result.

The fix is for append(x,y) to be `synchronized` on some object, and (this is the important part), for *every other method* that uses the lists to be `synchronized` on the *same object*.  Since only one thread can be `synchronized` on a given object at a given time, it will not be possible for any other thread to see the lists in an inconsistent state.

So, if thread A calls append(x,y), and thread B tries to look at the lists "at the same time", will thread B see the what the lists looked like *before* or *after* thread A did its work?  That's called a *data race*.  And with only the synchronization that I have described so far, there's no way to know which thread will win.  All we've done so far is to guarantee one particular invariant.

If it matters which thread wins the race, then that means that there is some higher-level invariant that also needs protection.  You will have to add more synchronization to protect that one too.  "Thread safety" -- two little words to name a subject that is both broad and deep.

Good Luck, and Have Fun!

Comment: This is a very good answer. But it is *very* general, and may not be the best answer to *this* question.

Comment: @Cruncher, It was my answer to mevtagezer's very first sentence, "I am trying to wrap my head around thread safety..."

Answer (score 0):

```
    // is synchronisation required?
    public BigDecimal getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    // is synchronisation required?
    public void setSomeValue(BigDecimal val) {
        someValue = val;
    }
```

I think **Yes** you are require to put the synchronization block because consider an example in which one thread is setting the value and at the same time other thread is trying to read from getter method, [like here in the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459543/java-synchronized-getters-and-setters) you will see the syncronization block.So, if you take your variable inside the method then you must require the synchronization block.