# Secure Queue for Threads without using Synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I gotta create a program that, given a number N of threads, these threads can Insert or Remove an element from a queue, but there are conditions for the threads to access the queue:

- if only one thread try to insert or remove an element, it will be able to;
- if two or more threads are trying at the same time, one will be able to, and the next one will execute its operations when the first one finishes.

I made it using synchronized blocks, just like that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class EditorThread extends Thread {

    static int N = 10; // number of threads
    static queue Q = new queue(); // shared queue
    private int number; //number of the thread

    public EditorThread(int n) {
        number = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();

        while (true) {
            int t = r.nextInt(2);
            if (t == 1) {
                int value = Q.get();
                if (value == -1) {
                    System.out.println("The Thread " + number + " couldnt get any element (empty queue)");
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("The Thread " + number + " got the element " + value );
                }
            }

            else {
                int n = r.nextInt(100);
                Q.put(n);
                System.out.println("The Thread " + number + " inserted the element " + n);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Thread t = new EditorThread(i);
            t.start();
        }

    }

}

class queue {
    node head;
    node tail;

    queue() {
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public synchronized int get() {
        if (head == null)
            return -1;
        int r = head.value;
        if (head != tail)
            head = head.next;
        else
            head = tail = null;
        return r;
    }

    public synchronized void put(int i) {
        node n = new node(i);
        if (head == null)
            head = tail = n;
        else {
            tail.next = n;
            tail = n;
        }
    }

}

class node {

    int value;
    node next;

    public node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

the run void is simple, it just loops forever while inserts or removes elements.

My question is, how can I follow that conditions without using synchronized?

How is it possible to guarantee mutual exclusion without the synchronized blocks?

EDIT: I cannot use things similar to synchronized (just like locks)

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation like `LinkedBlockingQueue`? These are, by contract, thread safe.

Comment: yeah, I'm doing it for learning

Comment: Are you able to use `Atomic*` classes?

Comment: whateever  you implement is going to be a recreation of synchronized method mate(to some extent), you may want to read this nice question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-of-atomic-volatile-synchronize

Comment: I cannot use atomic, but its possible to do some tricks, like making the threads static, so one thread can stop another ( but I couldn't use this safely )

Comment: @nafas, Not if he implements a non-blocking queue.  A thread-safe, non-blocking queue can be implemented without locks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm

Comment: You can't guarantee mutual exclusion without locks.  "locking" and "mutual exclusion" both mean the same thing.  You _can_ create a thread-safe queue without mutual exclusion/locking, but it will not be a _blocking_ queue.  Google for "wait free algorithm" and "lock free algorithm."

Answer (score 0):

No, and yes.

Fundamentally you need to use some form of synchronization to do this. There is no way to do it yourself without.

However there are classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package that provide exactly the sort of behaviour you need and do it while minimizing locking and the cost of synchronization as much as possible.

For example `LinkedBlockingQueue`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

If you really want to understand how this stuff works though you should also read up on Non Blocking Algorithms. The wiki page is a good start. In general a lot of very smart people who know exactly what they are doing have worked on the concurrent package though. Threading is hard to get right.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm