# How to use synchronized in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
object Foo {
 private var ctr = 0L

 def bar = {
   ctr = ctr + 1
   // do something with ctr
 }
}
```

The requirement is that a `ctr` value should be used only once. In my case the same value of `ctr` is getting reused. My theory is that this happens because `Foo.bar` is called concurrently in different threads (this is the only conclusion I could draw). I have the following modified code as a fix.

```
object Foo {
 private var ctr = 0L
 def getCtr = synchronized{
   ctr = ctr + 1
   ctr
 }
 def bar = {
   val currCtr = getCtr
   // do something with currCtr
 }
}
```

I could not find a good guide for using the `synchronized` method in Scala. Can anyone let me know if the above code will fix my problem.

EDIT: Based on the comments below, I think `AtomicLong` is the best solution for me:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
private val ctr = new AtomicLong
def getCtr = ctr.incrementAndGet
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this already https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html ? You could also use an AtomicLong.

Comment: I'd side-step the issue and use an `AtomicInteger`. Those are made for concurrent counters.

Comment: +1. I understand emphasis on higher-level concurrency (futures, actors, etc), but it's a pity definitive Scala books don't even _mention_ `obj.synchronized` syntax.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you don't want an `AtomicInteger`, here is how to use `synchronized`

```
object Foo {
 private var ctr = 0L
 def getCtr = this.synchronized {
   ctr = ctr + 1
   ctr
 }
 def bar = {
    val currCtr = getCtr
    // do something with currCtr
  }
}
```

You need to synchronize on some object. In this case on your current object which is `this`.

In short: Scala's format is (and the block can return a value)

```
this.synchronized {
   ctr = ctr + 1
   ctr
}
```

It is equivalent of java's

```
synchronized(this) {
   return ++ctr;   
}
```

Scala does not have `synchronized` methods as java, just blocks.

**Edit**

To answer the question from comment below: `synchronized` can be used as a method from class `AnyRef`:

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html

```
final def synchronized[T0](arg0: ⇒ T0): T0
```

so you are calling a method of your object, just like you would do `toString` and `this.toString`.

Comment: What happens if I skip `this`? The code does compile and seems to behave correctly.

Comment: Note that unlike `toString` it isn't _actually_ a method on `AnyRef`, the compiler just pretends it is.

Comment: Within an `object`, is `this.synchronized {...}` the same as `synchronized {...}`?

Comment: @Łukasz out of the two, `AtomicLong` or `synchronized`, which one is preferred?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as it works as a method. If you had class `A { def a = 3; def b = a; def c = this.a }` `b` and `c` would do the same. In general it is perfered not to use things like `synchronized`, `wait`, `notify` as they are low level and error prone. `AtomicLong` is also faster. You can read about synchronized vs atomics here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-of-atomic-volatile-synchronize

Comment: "It isn't actually a method on AnyRef, the compiler just pretends it is."

That's pretty much the story of Scala right there.