# Multiple users accessing a Singleton in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following class in Play for Scala annotated as a Singleton. The objective of the class is to get/close OLAP connections. Question: how to handle the fact that more than one user may access the singleton concurrently? In Java I'd use `synchronized`, but what about Scala?

```
@Singleton
class OlapConnectionPool () {

    def getConnection = {
       val dataSource = new SimpleOlapDataSource
       val config = new GenericObjectPool.Config
       //... some connection code

       new PooledOlapDataSource(dataSource, config)
    }

    def close (pods: PooledOlapDataSource) = pods.close

}
```

Comment: Since your singleton is apparently stateless, you don't need to worry about concurrent access ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use synchronized in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877487/how-to-use-synchronized-in-scala)

Comment: @C4stor how do you know it's stateless if i didn't include in the question the commented code?

Comment: Because I wouldn't think you'd omit such an important information by commenting it away ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us first address a potential issue in your code snippet - each time `getConnection` is called a new connection pool is created. This represents a resource leak as, most likely, a single connection pool would be sufficient. I would suggest the following refactor:

```
@Singleton
class OlapConnectionPool () {
  private val ds = {
    val dataSource = new SimpleOlapDataSource
    val config = new GenericObjectPool.Config
    //... some connection code 
    new PooledOlapDataSource(dataSource, config)
  }

  def getConnection() = ds.getConnection()
  def close() = ds.close()
}
```

Here `ds` is initialised only once upon singleton construction, so there is a single connection pool for the life-span duration of the singleton.

Singletons are thread-safe as longs as they are not publicly exposing shared state, for example, via public `var` members, and all the dependencies of the singleton are also thread-safe. Hence we need to determine if the dependency `PooledOlapDataSource` is thread-safe. I am guessing `PooledOlapDataSource` is from `pivot4j`, so inspecting `PooledOlapDataSource` source code we can see it depends on [`PoolableObjectFactory`](https://github.com/mysticfall/pivot4j/blob/fc15e0e1503e966d67d49d26ca3625854e296e6a/pivot4j-core/src/main/java/org/pivot4j/datasource/PooledOlapDataSource.java#L108), which according to [docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/PoolableObjectFactory.html) is thread-safe:

> PoolableObjectFactory must be thread-safe.

Furthermore if we inspect dependencies of `PoolableObjectFactory.getConnection` we arrive at [`borrowObject`](https://github.com/apache/commons-pool/blob/0e348d9c5e4649543f1975dc41a39d484c1607c5/src/java/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.java#L1058) call where we see bunch of `synchronized` sprinkled in. Therefore it is probably safe to conclude your singleton is thread-safe.

Also, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643080/why-use-singletone-controllers-in-play-2-5#answer-40653182) interesting answer where the author recommends to:

> In general, it is probably best to not use @Singleton unless you have
>   a fair understanding of immutability and thread-safety.