# thread safe for instance fields

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

when programming for a thread safe project, how to determine which field should be thread safe. for example we have a class in a project called TestThreadSafe in a multithread project.

```
public class TestThreadSafe  {
    public AtomicLong pCounter = new AtomicLong();
    public AtomicLong mCounter = new AtomicLong();
    protected final ConcurrentMap<K, V> Map = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();
    private ScheduledExecutorService ses;
    private String dir;
}
```

Here, why do not define ses and dir as final or volatile fields?

Comment: We don't know the usage of those fields. If they are not used in multi threading context, volatile is not required. If you are not changing the reference, final is not required

Comment: TestThreadSafe   is used in multi threading context

Answer (score 4):

Key notes:

1. If your variables are not modified by multiple threads, don't use anything
2. If your variable reference does not change after creation, use `final`
3. If your variable is modified by single thread and accessed by other threads, use `volatile`
4. If your variables are modified and accessed by multiple threads:
   a. Use `AtomicXXX` if your operations are Atomic - single step transaction
   b. Use `synchronized` or [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) API if you have a code block to be guarded

You can find more details about high level concurrency constructs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)

Related SE questions:

[What is the difference between atomic / volatile / synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-between-atomic-volatile-synchronized/37395582#37395582)

[What is meant by "thread-safe" code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code)

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to mark a field as `final` (you don't loose any performance, but gain compile time checks and threading related bonus - field will always have given value, not the default one).

As for `volatile` - it makes CPU optimizations (caches) go away so using such field will be slower.

`volatile` should be used if you share given field value between threads - where one thread is writing data to it and multiple (>= 1) threads read from it.

Comment: confused about instance field variable Modifier, which fields should be declared final,volatile or something else before the instance field variable. how to determine and how to decide, are there some standard to do that?

Comment: There is no standard, if there was java would do it for you. You need to look at the code end decide yourself. I personally add final modifiers everywhere and initialize fields in constructors.