# How to increment AtomicInteger twice?

Tags: java, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

I need to increment AtomicInteger twice, like:
++i;
++i;
By the endless ciycle, i want to increment counter twice and check it on the parity.
But i'm always getting the variable which was incremented once. How to fix it?

Comment: the question is not complete, add some code here to explain your question.

Comment: just call `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()`twice

Comment: Achilles didn`t work correctly

Comment: Achilles ,near 10k iteration variable was incremented once

Comment: Achilles, i am sure

Comment: share your code

Comment: public int increment() { 
    atomic.incrementAndGet();
    atomic.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println(atomic.get());
    return atomic.get(); 
  }

Comment: Your code works for me.  How about we see all your code?  And add it to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 15):

```
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(100);
    counter.addAndGet(2);
    System.out.println(counter);
```

or

```
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(100);        
    counter.incrementAndGet();
    counter.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: run it in the endless cycle and check it`s parity.

Comment: @ИльяАлександрович It works. Even if you put the incrementAndGet part into an infinite loop it still works. Did you put the initialization of the AtomicInteger (`final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(100);`) into a loop as well by any chance?

Comment: No. I put it to the another class.

Answer (score 3):

Gives me an even number every time:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(100);
        int limit = 100;
        while ( limit-- != 0 ){
            counter.incrementAndGet();
            counter.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(counter.get());
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose there aren't, unless atomic guarantees that stuff won't be optimized away, or something esoteric like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-between-atomic-volatile-synchronized

Comment: AFAIK the point of atomics is in case another thread changes a value.  If you've only got one thread, there's no reason to use them.