# Safe publication through final

Tags: java

Even after going though [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5), I am still not clear about how usage of final causes safe publication in the below code. Can someone give an easy-to-understand explanation.

```
public class SafeListener
{
    private final EventListener listener;

    private SafeListener()
    { 
         listener = new EventListener()
         {  public void onEvent(Event e)
            {  doSomething(e); }
          };
    }

    public static SafeListener newInstance(EventSource source)
    {    
          SafeListener safe = new SafeListener(); 
          source.registerListener(safe.listener);
          return safe;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited to add:  Interesting perspective on the [origins of Java and JSR-133's `final` behavior](http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/larval_objects_in_the_vm).

Canonical reference for how `final` works in the new JMM, for safe publication: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight

On simple review, I think your code represents "safe" publication to the `EventSource source` object, which presumably will be fielding event callbacks to `listener` in a different thread.  You are guaranteed that threads operating on the `safe.listener` reference passed will see a fully-initialized `listener` field.  This **does not** make any further guarantees about other synchronization issues associated with calls to `onEvent` or other interactions with the object's state.

What is guaranteed by your code is that, when `SafeListener`'s constructor returns a reference inside the static method, the `listener` field will not be seen in an unwritten state (even if there is no explicit synchronization).  For example:  Suppose a thread A calls `newInstance()`, resulting in an assignment to the `listener` field.  Suppose that a thread B is able to dereference the `listener` field.  Then, even absent any other synchronization, thread B is guaranteed to see the write `listener = new EventListener()...`.  If the field were not `final`, you would not receive that guarantee.  There are several (other) ways of providing the guarantee (explicit synchronization, use of an atomic reference, use of volatile) of varying performance and readability.

Not everything that's legal is advisable.  Suggest you take a look at [JCiP](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) and perhaps this [article on safe publication techniques](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html).

A recent, related question is here: ["Memory barriers and coding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964317/memory-barriers-and-coding-style-over-a-java-vm), ["Java multi-threading & Safe Publication"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication).

Comment: @iJeeves: Happy to do so, but it would help if you gave some example of what you mean by publication -- how do you intend client code to use the `SafeListener`, and in particular, access the `listener` field?  Are there any other synchronization constraints?

Comment: @iJeeves: Never mind, your code was adequate, I misread.  Amended my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, the specification for `final` (see @andersoj's answer) guarantees that when the constructor returns, the final field will have been properly initialized (as visible from all threads).

There is no such guarantee for non-final fields (which means that if another thread gets the freshly constructed object, the field may not have been set yet).

That this works is part of the JVM spec.

How it works would be a JVM implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [JSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.5)
Final field or the object reachable through a final reference can't be reordered with the initial load of a reference to that object. It is visible to all other threads after its construction.