# Are Immutable objects immune to improper publication?

Tags: java, multithreading, immutability, publish

It is an example from [JCiP](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/).

```
public class Unsafe {
    // Unsafe publication 
    public Holder holder;

    public void initialize() {
        holder = new Holder(42);
    }
}

public class Holder {
    private int n;

    public Holder(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
    public void assertSanity() {
        if (n != n) {
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
        }
    }
}
```

On page 34:

> [15] The problem here is not the Holder class itself, but that the
>   Holder is not properly published. However, Holder can be made immune
>   to improper publication by declaring the n field to be final, which
>   would make Holder immutable;

And from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974401/2961429):

> the specification for final (see @andersoj's answer) guarantees that
>   when the constructor returns, the final field will have been properly
>   initialized (as visible from all threads).

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking):

> For example, in Java if a call to a constructor has
>   been inlined then the shared variable may immediately be updated once
>   the storage has been allocated but before the inlined constructor
>   initializes the object

**My question is:**

Because : (could be wrong, I don't know.)

a) the shared variable may immediately be updated before the inlined constructor initializes the object.

b) the final field will be guaranteed to be properly initialized (as visible from all threads) ONLY when the constructor returns.

Is it possible that another thread sees the default value of `holder.n`? (i.e. Another thread gets a reference to `holder` before the `holder` constructor returns.)

If so, then how do you explain the statement below?

> Holder can be made immune to improper publication by declaring the n
>   field to be final, which would make Holder immutable

**EDIT:**
From JCiP. The definition of an immutable object:

> An object is immutable if:
>   x Its state cannot be modified after
>   construction;
>
> x All its fields are final;[12] and
>
> x It is properly
>   constructed (the this reference does not escape during construction).

So, by definition, immutable objects don't have "`this` reference escaping" problems. Right?

But will they suffer from [Out-of-order writes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html) in double-checked-locking pattern if not declared to be volatile?

Comment: The Java memory model guarantees safe publication without explicit synchronization for all immutable objects whose instance fields are declared final.

Comment: @scottb Incorrect. The constructor itself can leak the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An immutable object, e.g. `String`, appears to have the same state for all readers, regardless how its reference is obtained, even with improper synchronization and lack of happens-before relationship.

This is achieved by `final` field semantics introduced in Java 5. Data access through a final field has a stronger memory semantics, as defined in [jls-17.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1)

In terms of compiler reordering and memory barriers, there are more constraints when dealing with final fields, see [JSR-133 Cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html). The reordering you worried about won't happen.

And yes -- double-checked locking can be done through a final field in a wrapper; no `volatile` is required! But this approach is not necessarily faster, because two reads are needed.

---

Note that this semantics applies to individual final fields, not the entire object as a whole. For example, `String` contains a mutable field `hash`; nevertheless, `String` is considered immutable because its public behavior are only based on `final` fields.

A final field can point to a mutable object. For example, `String.value` is a `char[]` which is mutable. It's impractical to require that an immutable object is a tree of final fields.

```
final char[] value;

public String(args) {
    this.value = createFrom(args);
}
```

As long as we don't modify the content of `value` after constructor exit, it's fine.

We can modify the content of `value` in the constructor in any order, it doesn't matter.

```
public String(args) {
    this.value = new char[1];
    this.value[0] = 'x';  // modify after the field is assigned.
}
```

Another example

```
final Map map;
List list;

public Foo()
{
    map = new HashMap();
    list = listOf("etc", "etc", "etc");
    map.put("etc", list)
}
```

Any access ***through*** the final field will appear to be immutable, e.g. `foo.map.get("etc").get(2)`.

Access *not* through a final field does not -- `foo.list.get(2)` is not safe through improper publication, even though it reads the same destination.

---

Those are the design motivations. Now let's see how JLS formalizes it in [jls-17.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1)

A `freeze` action is defined at the constructor exit, as apposed to at the assignment of the final field. This allows us to write anywhere inside the constructor to populate internal state.

The usual problem of unsafe publication is the lack of happens-before (`hb`) relationship. Even if a read sees a write, it establishes nothing w.r.t other actions. But if a volatile read sees a volatile write, JMM establishes `hb` and an order among many actions.

The `final` field semantics wants to do the same thing, even with normal reads and writes, that is, even through unsafe publications. To do that, a memory chain (`mc`) order is added between any write seen by a read.

A `deferences()` order limits the semantics to accesses **through** the final field.

Let's revisit the `Foo` example to see how it works

```
tmp = new Foo()

    [w] write to list at index 2

    [f] freeze at constructor exit

shared = tmp;   [a]  a normal write

// Another Thread

foo = shared;   [r0] a normal read

if(foo!=null) // [r0] sees [a], therefore mc(a, r0)

    map = foo.map;          [r1] reads a final field

    map.get("etc").get(2)   [r2]
```

We have

```
hb(w, f), hb(f, a), mc(a, r1), and dereferences(r1, r2)
```

therefore `w` is visible to `r2`.

---

Essentially, through `Foo` wrapper, a map (which is mutable in itself) is published safely though unsafe publication... if that makes sense.

Can we use the wrapper to establish final field semantics then discard it? Like

```
Foo foo = new Foo();   // [w] [f]

shared_map = foo.map;  // [a]
```

Interestingly, JLS contains enough clauses to exclude such use case. I guess it's weakened so that more inner-thread optimizations are permitted, even with final fields.

---

Note that if `this` is leaked before the freeze action, final field semantics is not guaranteed.

However, we *can* safely leak `this` in a constructor *after* the freeze action, with constructor chaining.

```
-- class Bar

final int x;

Bar(int x, int ignore)
{
    this.x = x;  // assign to final
}  // [f] freeze action on this.x

public Bar(int x)
{ 
    this(x, 0);
    // [f] is reached!
    leak(this); 
}
```

This is safe as far as `x` is concerned; freeze action on `x` is defined at the exist of the constructor in which `x` is assigned. This was probably designed just to safely leak `this`.

Comment: Where can I find more information(like some books?) about the 2 partial orders: memory chain `mc()` and dereference chain `dereferences()` ?  I always find JLS pretty hard to understand. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know. If an author writes a book about `mc()` stuff, he's not going to sell any copy to recover the coffee expense. In the end, these formalizations don't really matter. We follow common use patterns and rules of thumbs. The language is designed for that. The spec is written for implementers.

Answer (score 2):

No, an immutable object can still be unsafely published if the constructor leaks a reference to `this` before returning (which is where the happens-before kicks in).

The two likely routes for the reference leak are if the constructor attempts to register the new object for callbacks (such as as an event listener on some constructor parameter) or with a registry or, more subtly, calls a non-final method that is overridden to do the same thing.

Comment: I read about the "this reference escaping" section in JCiP. My question is: Apart from the leaking from within the constructor,  is there any other way that "this reference" might escape? For example, does the "double-checked-locking" problem count as  an example of "this reference escaping"?

Comment: @du369 Double-checked locking is an entirely different construct. The only way for an unconstructed reference to leak is from the constructor, either directly (passing or assigning `this`) or indirectly (calling methods on itself that have access to `this` and leak it).

Comment: Leaking `this` from constructors is not an issue that is particular or unique to immutable objects.  Any object that obtains a reference to an incompletely constructed instance can view that instance in an inconsistent or invalid state, mutable or not.  Assuming that `this` is not leaked, the Java memory model enables the presumption of safe publication for truly immutable objects.

Comment: @scottb No, it's not unique to immutable objects, but it *is* the only manner in which an immutable object can be seen in an inconsistent state.