# Why is the volatile field copied to a local variable when doing double check locking

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, effective-java

I am reading about double check locking from `Effective Java`.  The code does the following:

```
private volatile FieldType field;  
FieldType getField() {  
    FieldType result = field;  
    if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)  
        synchronized(this) {   
        result = field;  
        if (result == null) // Second check (with locking)  
            field = result = computeFieldValue();  
        }  
    }  
    return result;  
}
```

It says that using `result` seems unneeded but actually ensures that the `field` is only read only once in the common case where it is already initialized.

But I don't understand this.  What is the difference with doing `if(field == null)` directly?  I don't understand  why `if (result == null)` is different, let alone better as stated.

Comment: Is `result` being used further down the method?

Comment: We'd like to see "etc" ...  What's the page reference for Effective Java?  I don't have my copy with me - but others might.

Comment: See [Is volatile expensive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866/is-volatile-expensive)

Comment: Yes those two links in that question @assylias are excellent, I still have them bookmarked. Brian Goetz is very good at explaining things. Highly recommended and VERY much relevant today even though written 8years ago (2004).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thinking in that example is that result/field will be used more than once further down I guess. Accessing `result` is cheaper (it's not volatile).

You have a second volatile read when doing the return otherwise.

Use the initializaton on demand holder pattern instead if you need to do this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom

Adding some of my clarifications in the comments to the answer itself for well... clarity:

Short version: A local variable can just be in a register in (one of) the cpu(s) (and in one of the cpu's cores if multiple etc). That's as fast as it gets. A volatile variable must be checked for changes in other cores/caches/cpus/memory, but the details can be very hardware specific (cache lines, memory barriers etc). But also jvm specific, (the hotspot server compiler might hoist non volatile variables for example) and it imposes limits on reordering instructions for possible performance gains as well

Comment: You might want to mention what `volatile` implies, in Java: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java

Comment: @Pulsar:So it is more expensive to access a `volatile`?

Comment: @Jim - yes. Read the link I pasted above.

Comment: Well that's a rather complicated subject though, for the details I mean. But a good start would be the java memory model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model

Comment: Short version: A local variable can just be in a register in (one of) the cpu(s) (and in one of the cpu's cores if multiple etc). That's as fast as it gets. A volatile variable must be checked for changes in other cores/caches/cpus/memory, but the details can be very hardware specific (cache lines, memory barriers etc). But also jvm specific, (the hotspot server compiler might hoist non volatile variables for example) and it imposes limits on reordering instructions for possible performance gains as well.

Comment: @Pulsar:But during the assignment to `result` isn't the `volatile field` accessed anyway?So don't we have the overhead access anyway?

Comment: For short, reading a volatile is like entering a synchronized block, and writing to it is like leaving a synchronized block

Comment: Yes @Jim and that is why I said "The thinking in that example is that result/field will be **used more than once** further down I guess." So we only have it once instead of multiple. But we didn't have the entire code block from you then :)

Comment: You have a second volatile read when doing the return otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation is on the next page (emphasis by me):

> What this variable does is to ensure that field is
>   read only once in the common case where it’s already initialized. While not
>   strictly necessary, **this may improve performance** and is more elegant by the standards
>   applied to low-level concurrent programming. On my machine, the method
>   above is about 25 percent faster than the obvious version without a local variable.

For reference, the quote is from p. 284 of Item 71: *Use lazy initialization judiciously* in Effective Java 2nd Edition.

**Update**: the difference between reading a local vs a volatile variable is that the former *may* be optimized better. Volatile variables can't be stored in registers or caches, nor memory operations on them reordered. Moreover, reading a volatile variable may trigger memory synchronization between different threads.

See *Java Concurrency in Practice*, section 3.1.4: *Volatile Variables* for more details.

Comment: That does not really answer the question and the OP seems to have seen that explanation already.

Comment: @PeterTorok:This is exactly what I ask.Why does this improve performance?

Comment: @assylias, well, that wasn't at all obvious (to me). Anyway, I've added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @PéterTörök You could also mention that each read of a `volatile` is like an enter-synchronized-block operation in that it must synchronizes any thread-local caches with the main memory. This may be the most expensive part.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Missed the point of the last sentence.

Comment: @Marko, your explanation is more precise anyway, so thanks :-)

Comment: Good answer. Good to see some actual references and not just espoused theory on SO for a change!