# Access to volatile fields through local variables

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, volatile

This question is somewhat continuation and expansion of this one, as I think **perfect** question: [How does assigning to a local variable help here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512782/how-does-assigning-to-a-local-variable-help-here/10512895#10512895)

This question based on `Item 71` of `Effective Java`, where it is suggested to speed up performance by introducing local variable in purpose of `volatile` field access:

```
private volatile FieldType field;  
FieldType getField() {  
    FieldType result = field;  
    if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)  
        synchronized(this) {   
        result = field;  
        if (result == null) // Second check (with locking)  
            field = result = computeFieldValue();  
        }  
    }  
    return result;  
}
```

So, **my** question is more common:

**should we always access to `volatile` fields through assigning their values to local variables?** *(in order to archive best performance)*.

I.e. some idiom:

1. we have some `volatile` field, call it just `volatileField`;
2. if we want to read its value in multi-thread method, we should:

   1. create local variable with same type: `localVolatileVariable`
   2. assign value of volatile field: `localVolatileVariable = volatileField`
   3. read value from this local copy, e.g.:

      ```
      if (localVolatileVariable != null) { ... }
      ```

Comment: How is that question different than the one you link to? It seems you want to have an answer to a situation broader than the "initialize lazy-loaded field" scenario of that particular piece of code shown there (and here). But then the answer cannot be more than "it depends", I am afraid.

Comment: It is different, that I just want to understand: is this optimization applicable only for the particular case, described in `Item 71`, or  it is common approach for `volatile` fields reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *must* assign volatile variables to local fields if you plan on doing any sort of multi-step logic (assuming of course, that the field is mutable).

for instance:

```
volatile String _field;

public int getFieldLength() {
  String tmp = _field;
  if(tmp != null) {
    return tmp.length();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

if you did not use a local copy of `_field`, then the value could change between the "if" test and the "length()" method call, potentially resulting in an NPE.

this is besides the obvious benefit of a speed improvement by not doing more than one volatile read.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides of a coin.

On the one hand assignment to a volatile works like a memory barrier and it's very unlikely that JIT will reorder assignment with computeFieldValue invocation.

On the other hand in theory this code breaks JMM. Because for some reasons some **JVM is allowed to reorder** computeFieldValue with assignment and you see partially initialized object. This is possible as long as variable read is not order with variable write.

```
field = result = computeFieldValue();
```

**does not happen before**

```
if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)
```

As long as java code supposed to be "write once run everywhere" DCL is a bad practice and should be avoided. This code is broken and is not a point of consideration.

If you have multiple reads of a volatile variable in a method, by assigning it to a local variable first you minimize such reads, which are more expensive. But I don't think, that you get a performance boost. This is likely to be a theoretical improvement. Such optimization should be left to JIT and is not a point of developer's considerations. I agree with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090377/2031799).

Comment: On the one hand assignment to a volatile works -> he is not writing to a volatile, he is reading one.

Comment: "field = result = computeFieldValue()" here he writes. This is a variation of a classic DCL anti pattern.

Comment: fyi, the DCL pattern shown in the OP is _not_ broken (it is the "fixed" version).  not sure from your post whether you are implying that it is correct or not.

Comment: There are some things in Java, which are working, but you should avoid them. DCL is one of those.

Comment: @Mikhail http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5 "If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)." That means "if (result == null)" does happen before "field = result = computeFieldValue(); "

Answer (score 0):

Instead of potentially doing **TWO** reads of a volatile variables, he does just one.
Reading volatile is probably a bit slower the a usual variable. But even if so, we are talking about nano seconds here.

Comment: Well, but Joshua Bloch is speaking about 25% better performance on his machine :)

Comment: @Andremoniy that was some time ago he wrote that. And 25% from 1 nano seconds si still very little. Too little to me.