# Why access volatile variable is about 100 slower than member?

Tags: java, performance, volatile

Here I wrote a test about access speed of local, member, volatile member:

```
public class VolatileTest {

public int member = -100;

public volatile int volatileMember = -100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int testloop = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= testloop; i++) {
        System.out.println("Round:" + i);
        VolatileTest vt = new VolatileTest();
        vt.runTest();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void runTest() {
    int local = -100;

    int loop = 1;
    int loop2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    long startTime;

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Empty:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
            local++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
            local--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Local:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
            member++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
            member--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Member:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
            volatileMember++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < loop2; j++) {
            volatileMember--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("VMember:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

}
}
```

And here is a result on my X220 (I5 CPU):

**Round:1**
*Empty:5
Local:10
Member:312
VMember:33378*

**Round:2**
*Empty:31
Local:0
Member:294
VMember:33180*

**Round:3**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:306
VMember:33085*

**Round:4**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:300
VMember:33066*

**Round:5**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:303
VMember:33078*

**Round:6**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:299
VMember:33398*

**Round:7**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:305
VMember:33139*

**Round:8**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:307
VMember:33490*

**Round:9**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:350
VMember:35291*

**Round:10**
*Empty:0
Local:0
Member:332
VMember:33838*

It surprised me that access to volatile member is 100 times slower than normal member. I know there is some highlight feature about volatile member, such as a modification to it will be visible for all thread immediately, access point to volatile variable plays a role of "memory barrier". But can all these side effect be the main cause of 100 times slow?

PS: I also did a test on a Core II CPU machine. It is about 9:50, about 5 times slow. seems like this is also related to CPU arch. 5 times is still big, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is volatile expensive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866/is-volatile-expensive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acess to `volatile` prevents some JIT optimisaton.  This is especially important if you have a loop which doesn't really do anything as the JIT can optimise such loops away (unless you have a volatile field)  If you run the loops "long" the descrepancy should increase more.

In more realistic test, you might expect `volatile` to take between 30% and 10x slower for cirtical code.  In most real programs it makes very little difference because the CPU is smart enough to "realise" that only one core is using the volatile field and cache it rather than using main memory.

Answer (score 9):

The volatile members are never cached, so they are read directly from the main memory.

Answer (score 4):

Access to a `volatile` variable prevents the CPU from re-ordering the instructions before and after the access, and this generally slows down execution.

Answer (score 0):

Using volatile will read from the memory directly so that every core of cpu will get the change at next get from the variable, there's no cpu cache used, which will not use register, L1~L3 cache tech, reading from

1. register 1 clock cycle
2. L1 cache 4 clock cycle
3. L2 cache 11 clock cycle
4. L3 cache 30~40 clock cycle
5. Memory   100+ clock cycle

That's why your result is about 100 times slower when using volatile.