# About Singleton pattern in java, instead of assigning static variable to new local variable in method, why not use directly static variable?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I haven't understood what the code's purpose => **DataProvider instance = sInstance;** is in below method. Anyone help me to explain in detail ? Why don't use directly sInstance ?

```
private static volatile DataProvider sInstance = null;
 public static DataProvider getInstance() {
     DataProvider instance = sInstance;
      if (instance == null) {
          synchronized (DataProvider.class) {
              instance = sInstance;
              if (instance == null) {
                  instance = sInstance = new DataProvider();
              }
          }
      }
      return instance;
  }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you should use `enum` instead

Comment: Where did you get the code from? It looks overcomplicated.

Comment: It's just a micro-optimization.

Comment: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/LocationController.java
@Juan its code from telegram

Comment: @Radiodef may u explan in detail :( I don't know why need to assign to local variable before using => DataProvider instance = sInstance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the book Prentice.Hall.Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008 of Joshua Bloch,

> In particular, the need for the local variable result may be unclear.
>   What this variable does is to ensure that field is read only once in
>   the common case where it’s already initialized. While not strictly
>   necessary, this may improve performance and is more elegant by the
>   standards applied to low-level concurrent programming. On my machine,
>   the method above is about 25 percent faster than the obvious version
>   without a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is used as a lazy initialization (e.i. only create the singleton instance when needed). The problem with this code is that it is broken. Apparently even when using the synchronize block, there is a posaibility that things goes wrong (due to raceconditions). So do not use this method if you want to be safe!

Alternatives:
Using a direct assignment (like you sugessted);

```
private static volatile DataProvider sInstance = new DataProvider();
```

Or using a enum (as suggested by @MadProgrammer);

```
public enum DataProvider
{

    INSTANCE;

    // singleton content
}
```

Comment: I want to know why we should assign to local variable => DataProvider instance = sInstance;

Comment: :( may you explain in detail for me :(

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is Volatile. As @Hien Nguyen's answer, it improve 25% performance. Cause Volatile is always get data from main memory instead of cache, so it's too slow. Declare instance = sInstance to avoid read data from main memory multiple time (slow). 
There're 3 time we read data from sInstance if we don't use temp variable, so we use temp variable will imporve performance.

See this topic to understand why access Volatile is slow: [Why access volatile variable is about 100 slower than member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132087/why-access-volatile-variable-is-about-100-slower-than-member)

Your answer maybe the same as this topic: [Java: using a local variable in double check idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222291/java-using-a-local-variable-in-double-check-idiom)