# How to correctly use signaling via shared objects?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently studying about signaling in threads and came across this article for signaling via shared objects,
 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html

It says that we can create a shared object and pass that object to threads which, threads can use to signal each other.

Following is the snippet provided for shared object,

```
public class MySignal{
  protected boolean hasDataToProcess = false;

  public synchronized boolean hasDataToProcess(){
    return this.hasDataToProcess;
  }

  public synchronized void setHasDataToProcess(boolean hasData){
    this.hasDataToProcess = hasData;  
  }
}
```

I tried to use it in my class as,

```
class MySignal {
    boolean hasDataToProcess = false;

    public MySignal(boolean defaultValue) {
        this.hasDataToProcess = defaultValue;
    }

    public synchronized boolean hasDataToProcess() {
        return this.hasDataToProcess;
    }

    public synchronized void setHasDataToProcess(boolean hasDataToProcess) {
        this.hasDataToProcess = hasDataToProcess;
    }
}

class MyThreadRunnable implements Runnable {
    MySignal sharedSignal;

    MyThreadRunnable(MySignal signal) {
        this.sharedSignal = signal;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " starts running..");

        synchronized (sharedSignal) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " accessing sharedSignal");

            while(sharedSignal.hasDataToProcess()) {
                sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(false);
                try {
                      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " going to sleep");
                      Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(true);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended.");
        }
    }

}

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySignal mySignal = new MySignal(true);

        MyThreadRunnable t1 = new MyThreadRunnable(mySignal);
        MyThreadRunnable t2 = new MyThreadRunnable(mySignal);

        Thread t3 = new Thread(t1);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(t2);

        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

This provided the expected output as,

```
Thread-1 starts running..
Thread-0 starts running..
Thread-1 accessing sharedSignal
Thread-1 going to sleep
Thread-1 ended.
Thread-0 accessing sharedSignal
Thread-0 going to sleep
Thread-0 ended.
```

But even if I remove the *synchronized* on the MySignal methods, this provides the same output as *sharedSignal* object is locked by one of the threads.
And, if I remove only the *synchronized* in *run()*, it does not work properly as one of the threads end before even going to sleep.

So this code is only running correctly due to the lock on *sharedSignal* object.

Is this how the signaling has to be used?
My intuition says that I've missed something. I tried searching for a good example but no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any variable shared across threads must be `volatile`, eg `protected volatile boolean hasDataToProcess = false;`, because otherwise threads may (and usually do) cache the value, effectively ignoring changes to it made in other threads.

Comment: @Bohemain I have this doubt as well. Since objects are stored on the heap, I don't need to declare them volatile, do I? For primitives, caching makes sense. Is it the same for objects as well?

Comment: @Bohemian I have the same doubt as Prashant. Do we need to put *volatile* for object members too for signaling to work properly?

Comment: As a note, regardless of the semantics right here, the class `AtomicBoolean` was added for exactly this case (though a `ConcurrentQueue` is usually a better design choice). Concurrency is hard; use the tools that have been carefully tested to make it easier.

Comment: Yes, for objects too. The *reference* to objects, and the *value* of primitives, must be volatile to guarantee visibility of changes in threads other then the one that made the change.

Comment: After reading that article, it's clear that it was obsolete 8 years before it was written with the release of Java 6.

Comment: @Bohemian The question as phrased is a bit unclear. Marking a variable `volatile` will not make _changes to the members of the object referenced_ visible, only the immediately marked variable.

Comment: @Bohemian Wouldn't that create a performance issue if the object size is large and frequent read/write is happening on the object's members?

Comment: with `synchronized` statement, the signal does nothing, since whole block is already synchronized; without it, the problem is logic: first thread sees `true` enter loop and sets to `false`, 2nd  thread sees `false`, does not enter loop and terminates (acting as implemented, expected - there is no data to process, since 1st thread is already processing it) Note: checking flag and setting flag should be done in an atomic way (synchronized)

Comment: @Bohemian You're incorrect - `volatile` is not required, correctly published data can be achieved with only `synchronized` (there are a few other ways too but they are less generally usable - such as starting/joining threads, etc.) - please read up on the Java Memory Model (section 17.4 of the JLS - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But even if I remove the synchronized on the MySignal methods, this
>   provides the same output as sharedSignal object is locked by one of
>   the threads

Removing the `synchronized` from the methods won't make a difference as there is already a `synchronized` block guarding the method access from different threads.

> And, if I remove only the synchronized in run(), it does not work
>   properly as one of the threads end before even going to sleep.

But if you remove the the `synchronized` block then the contents of the block are not executed in an atomic way.

What I mean is without the `synchronized` block the any thread can call the `sharedSignal.hasDataToProcess()` get the lock on the `MySignal` object and then release it after it is done with the method then another thread is free to call the `sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(false);` as the lock on the `MySignal` instance was already released by the earlier thread when it was done with the method.

```
//Acquires lock for the entire block
synchronized (sharedSignal) { 
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " accessing sharedSignal");
     while(sharedSignal.hasDataToProcess()) {
           sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(false);
             try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " going to sleep");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             }
      }        
      sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(true);
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended.");
}
```

Now without the `synchronized` block, the code of the block is not executed in an *atomic* way:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " accessing sharedSignal");
//say thread1 acquires lock here
while(sharedSignal.hasDataToProcess()) {
     //thread1 releases lock here, thread2 can acquire lock on the same object
     sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(false);
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " going to sleep");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
   }        
   sharedSignal.setHasDataToProcess(true);
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended.");
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the *synchronized* on method is only working from, when the thread accesses it and till the method execution is finished.

Comment: @dSanders yes, the thread holds the lock on the `this` instance for a `synchronized` instance method, so when it starts executing it acquires it and when its done it will release the lock.

Comment: So in order to use the signaling using shared objects, we **always** need to put a lock on the shared object and, without it there is no guarantee that signaling  will work properly?

Comment: @dSanders lock should be acquired for exclusive access to a block of code and also for using the wait/notify mechanism used in thread signalling. Plus as Bohemian said mark your flag as volatile otherwise some updates might not be seen by threads.

Comment: Okay, so in order to use shared objects, we need to make its members *volatile* and, put locks on only those blocks of code which should be executed strictly by one thread at a time.

Comment: And in the presented example, it should be on the *sharedSignal* object.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. 
One more thing, wouldn't putting volatile on objects members create a performance issue if frequent read/write is happening on that shared object ?

Comment: @dSanders you can find the explanation of the volatile cost in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866/is-volatile-expensive)

Comment: I think there is no need for `volatile`, JLS suggest it is an alternative to locking (my emphasis); "As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that, conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables. The Java programming language provides a **second mechanism**, volatile fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes."